# Display Back and Reload Buttons in PWA (Progressive Web App)

Tags: progressive-web-apps

How do I add these buttons (Back and Refresh) in PWA?

it should be the buttons is show up in top left application [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNZKp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Using Javascript, try:

Back:

```
history.back();
```

Reload:

```
window.location.reload();
```

See [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/go) for History.go() for more options